# Filtrar array pela primeira letra

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um array de objetos e preciso separá-lo pelas letras do alfabeto, portanto, preciso limitar os itens pela letra correspondente.

Exemplo:

```
A - Aston Martin

B - Bugatti
```

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
 .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.alphabet = [
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
    ];
  
    $scope.brands = [
        {"brand": "Ferrari"},
        {"brand": "Aston Martin"},
        {"brand": "Koenigsegg"},
        {"brand": "Lamborghini"},
        {"brand": "Bugatti"},
        {"brand": "Maserati"},
        {"brand": "Pagani"},
        {"brand": "Porsche"}
    ]
 });
```

```css
.multi-column {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">    
    <div class="row">
      <div id="{{letter}}" class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet">
        <h2>{{letter}}</h2>
        <ul class="list-unstyled multi-column">
          <li ng-repeat="x in brands"><a href="">{{x.brand}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Também coloque no site [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/brdppl/pen/VdQZbp)

E assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma função e nela faça um filtro:

```
$scope.filtrar = function(letter) {
  return $scope.brands.filter(b => b.brand[0] === letter);
}
```

depois chame ela no laço `ng-repeat="x in filtrar(letter)"`, diferente de `ng-show` a função irá retornar apenas os elementos que comecem com a letra informada no parâmetro `letter`, já `ng-show` irá renderizar os elementos e mostrar os comecem com `letter` e os outros elementos ficaram na pagina em oculto.

#### Código funcionando

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
 .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.alphabet = [
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
    ];
  
    $scope.brands = [
        {"brand": "Ferrari"},
        {"brand": "Aston Martin"},
        {"brand": "Koenigsegg"},
        {"brand": "Lamborghini"},
        {"brand": "Bugatti"},
        {"brand": "Maserati"},
        {"brand": "Pagani"},
        {"brand": "Porsche"}
    ];
  
    $scope.filtrar = function(letter) {
      return $scope.brands.filter(b => b.brand[0] === letter);
    }
 });
```

```css
.multi-column {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">    
    <div class="row">
      <div id="{{letter}}" class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet">
        <h2>{{letter}}</h2>
        <ul class="list-unstyled multi-column">
          <li ng-repeat="x in filtrar(letter)"><a href="">{{x.brand}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

#### Referência

- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas podemos fazer isso com o `ng-show`, validando se a primeira letra da marca for igual a letra do agrupamento exibe, senão ignora. Olha como ficou.

Adicionei:

```
ng-show="x.brand[0] == letter"
```

Código completo:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
 .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.alphabet = [
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
    ];
  
    $scope.brands = [
        {"brand": "Ferrari"},
        {"brand": "Aston Martin"},
        {"brand": "Koenigsegg"},
        {"brand": "Lamborghini"},
        {"brand": "Bugatti"},
        {"brand": "Maserati"},
        {"brand": "Pagani"},
        {"brand": "Porsche"}
    ]
 });
```

```css
.multi-column {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">    
    <div class="row">
      <div id="{{letter}}" class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet">
        <h2>{{letter}}</h2>
        <ul class="list-unstyled multi-column">
          <li ng-repeat="x in brands" ng-show="x.brand[0] == letter"><a href="">{{x.brand}}</a></li>
          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Funcionou muito bem. Simples mas eficaz.